# OpenCV return None whan imread is called with GDAL support

Tags: python, opencv, gis, gdal, geotiff

I have a very simple program in python with OpenCV and GDAL. In this program i read GeoTiff image with the following line

```
image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], cv2.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

The problem is for a specific image `imread` return `None`. I am using images from: https://www.sensefly.com/drones/example-datasets.html

Image in `Assessing crops with RGB imagery (eBee SQ) > Map (orthomosaic)` works well. Its size is: 19428, 19784 with 4 bands.

Image in `Urban mapping (eBee Plus/senseFly S.O.D.A.) > Map (orthomosaic)` doesn't work. Its size is: 26747, 25388 and 4 bands.

Any help to figure out what is the problem?

Edit: I tried the solution suggested by @en_lorithai and it works, the problem is then I need to do some image processing with OpenCV and the image loaded by GDAL has several issues

- GDAL load images as RGB instead of BGR (used by default in OpenCV)
- The image shape expected by OpenCV is (width, height, channels) and GDAL return an image with (channels, width, height) shape
- The image returned by GDAL is flipped in Y-axe and rotate clockwise by 90 degree.

The image loaded by OpenCV is (resized to 700x700):

[image: image loaded by OpenCV (resized to 700x700]

The image loaded by GDAL (after change shape, of course) is (resized to 700x700)

[image: imaged loaded by GDAL (resized to 700x700)]

Finally, If I try to convert this image from BGR to RGB with

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

I get (resized to 700x700)

[image: GDAL image converted to BGR]

I can convert from GDAL format to OpenCV format with the following code

```
image = ds.ReadAsArray() #Load image with GDAL
tmp = image.copy()
image[0] = tmp[2,:,:] # swap read channel and blue channel
image[2] = tmp[0,:,:]
image = np.swapaxes(image,2,0) # convert from (height, width, channels) to (channels, height, width)

image = cv2.flip(image,0) # flip in Y-axis
image = cv2.transpose(image) # Rotate by 90 degress (clockwise)
image = cv2.flip(image,1)
```

The problem is I think that this is a very slow process and I want to know if there is a automatic convert-process.

Comment: This is probably because of the bit depth of the image you are trying to open. Opencv is a bit strict in regards to that, and to make things worse it doesn't give you any error when it gets something it doesn't handle. If you are using gdal you can use that to open the image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and open the image in gdal instead

```
from osgeo import gdal

g_image = gdal.Open('161104_hq_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif')
a_image = g_image.ReadAsArray()
```

can't test as i don't have enough available memory to open that image.

Edit: equivalent operation on another image

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g_image = gdal.Open('Water-scenes-014.jpg') # 3 channel rgb image
a_image = g_image.ReadAsArray()
s_image = np.dstack((a_image[0],a_image[1],a_image[2]))
plt.imshow(s_image) # show image in matplotlib (no need for color swap)
s_image = cv2.cvtColor(s_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # colorswap for cv
cv2.imshow('name',s_image)
```

Another method of getting individual bands from gdal

```
g_image = gdal.Open('image_name.PNG')
band1 = g_image.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

You can then do a numpy dstack of each of the bands.

Comment: With this example it loads image, but when I call `cv2.imshow` the image is loaded with wrong shape (it is (4,X,Y) instead of (X,Y,4), wrong color (channels are swapped) and flipped in Y and rotated in -90 degrees (in horizontal). is there anyway to correct it instead of doing that manually (I mean, I can use `np.swapaxes` to reshape, `flip` to unflip and `image[0] = tmp[2,:,:]` `image[2] = tmp[0,:,:]` to swap channels but it is very slow)

Comment: @RdlP The reason for the colorswap is because of opencv. It uses BGR instead of RGB (which gdal uses). You can change the color with either numpy methods or Opencvs own function: cv2.cvtColor(a_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR). The shape change will require numpy methods/functions, but the image is bloody massive and will be somewhat slow regardless. I can't say if the image flip is a result of opencv or gdal or if the original image just is that way (My laptop doesn't have enough memory to open the thing).

Comment: @en_lorithaiI add extra info to the main question

Comment: @RdlP Yeah, i got a similar method: g_image = gdal.Open('Water-scenes-014.jpg')
a_image = g_image.ReadAsArray()
s_image = np.dstack((a_image[0],a_image[1],a_image[2]))
s_image = cv2.cvtColor(s_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow('name',s_image). Thing is, my computer just does not compute when trying to open exactly your image and i see that that image has 4 channels, not 3 (but i think the equivalent should be np.dstack((a_image[0],a_image[1],a_image[2],a_image[3])) for you). If you want to avoid the colorswap, you can use plt.imshow() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have marked this answers as correct, because you are point me in the right way (using GDAL to open the image). I am going to research if there is any automatic method to convert from GDAL images to OpenCV